# Links between org files

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Say I have two org files, `file1.org` and `file2.org` on disk (let's assume they are in the same directory). How can create a link on `file1.org` to `file2.org`?

Once I have the link on `file1.org`, let's assume I have cursor (point) sitting on that link. How can I tell Emacs to show me the corresponding file?

Finally, what if I want to create a link to a specific item of `file2.org` ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the `C-c C-l` shortcut to create link and use the syntax

```
file:./file2.org
```

and use `C-c C-o` with cursor on link to visit that link.

To link to a specific item, use

```
     file:projects.org::*task title            heading search in Org file
```

the doc: http://orgmode.org/org.html#External-links

you can even search for words:

```
file:projects.org::some words
```

Comment: Also `org-store-link` will store the current buffer/position as a link so you can easily insert it with `C-c C-l`. I recommend binding it to `C-c l` for symmetry with `org-insert-link`.

Comment: `C-u C-c C-l` directly opens the mini buffer with `file: [current path]`

Answer (score 4):

I like to use `org-id-copy`. It's kind of a precision instrument compared
to the other methods that give you troubles when there are many candidates.

After the call, current heading will have `ID` set in its property drawer.
The `ID` looks like `5d76eafc-94f6-47b1-ae4c-a7e917986fd1` and it's in your kill ring now.
You can insert with <kbd>C-c C-l</kbd> to make it look like

```
[[id:5d76eafc-94f6-47b1-ae4c-a7e917986fd1][link]]
```

You can see a sample usage within one file at https://gist.github.com/abo-abo/6040382 ,
but it also works across multiple files.

Comment: How to update the cache of IDs->locations after renaming files outside of emacs?